# How to restrict dragging behaviour of any component or container while scrolling is enabled in CodeName One?

Tags: codenameone

I want to make scrollable component or container (i.e. List or ListContainer). In order to apply this, I'm setting 'setScrollable(true)' property.

But if I apply scrollable property to specific component or container, it behaves like it's dragging within the given area.

So how to make only scrollable component without making it draggable ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't nest scrollables. The parent forms content pane is scrollable by default.

Invoking `setScrollable` is usually a mistake since you need to use either `setScrollableX` or `setScrollableY`.